# Please create tag for [aws-ssm]

Tags: support, tags

May we have a tag created for [aws-ssm]?

I asked a question relating to AWS Systems Manager here, but I can't create a tag without enough reputation.

[Ansible to get AWS SSM Parameter Store and fail on Secure Strings](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15164/ansible-to-get-aws-ssm-parameter-store-and-fail-on-secure-strings)

Comment: done: [tag:amazon-ssm] .. welcome to DevOps SE!

Comment: @PeterMuryshkin - Thank you! Would you mind changing it from [amazon-ssm] to [aws-ssm] to match other tags like it?